# TIMENOW() subtraction

Tags: formula, time

I am trying to find out the difference between the current time and 5PM. I tried numerous variations and I just can't make sense of the results I am getting.

Lets say current time is 15:36 (3:34 PM)

When I run this formula

`(TIMENOW() - TIMEVALUE("00:17:00.000"))`

I get the following:

> 83949787

Given the fact that time time is 15:36 and I want to discover how long till 17:00 (5PM) I would expect one of these:

> 1h 24m

or

> 104 (minutes)

or

> 6,240 (seconds)

or

> 6,240,000 (milliseconds)

I can't make sense of this. Is this a fraction of a day, milliseconds....a decimal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeNow()` returns the current time in GMT.  When the user views a Time field it's converted to their local timezone, but the value in the field is also always stored as GMT.  The almost-84 million number you're getting is the result of subtracting a later timevalue from an earlier one - rather than give a negative number, the system appears to calculate it as if the second number was actually that time the previous day.  There are 84,400,000 milliseconds in a day, so your number would indicate the actual value from `TimeNow()` is just after midnight.  You said you were trying at 3:34 PM Local time, so I'm guessing your offset is set to UTC -9:30 (French Polynesia) which would give a GMT time of 00:04, just before your subtracted value of 00:17.

Since you said you wanted to test since 5 PM local time, you'll need to account for your time offset, so your formula should be the following to get the time in milliseconds:

```
TIMENOW() - (TIMEVALUE('17:00:00.000') + (9.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
```

Comment: I thought this was surely the case but I could not get the math to work out in my local time zone. Have you been able to get a working example in a set time zone? (I may just be bad at math).

Comment: @DavidReed Changing the 9.5 to your local time (and + to - if you are ahead of GMT) ought to work.

Answer (score -3):

Sample Date Formulas
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5

Finding the Number of Business Hours Between Two Date/Times
The formula for finding business hours between two Date/Time values expands on the formula for finding elapsed business days. It works on the same principle of using a reference Date/Time, in this case 1/8/1900 at 16:00 GMT (9 a.m. PDT), and then finding your Dates’ respective distances from that reference. The formula rounds the value it finds to the nearest hour and assumes an 8–hour, 9 a.m. – 5 p.m. work day.

You can change the eights in the formula to account for a longer or shorter work day. If you live in a different time zone or your work day doesn’t start at 9:00 a.m., change the reference time to the start of your work day in GMT. See A Note About Date/Time and Time Zones for more information.

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking about Time only, not about Date or DateTime.

Comment: Once he has the business days, getting time from that is very easy.